# How do I run arbitrary SQL on DBeaver?

Tags: dbeaver

Ok, so this may seem like a stupid question but I'm fighting DBeaver and so far it's winning and Google is refusing to pick a side.

I've worked out how to explore the database, view the structure of tables, I can even view the data of a table and filter it.

But if I just want to run an arbitrary SQL statement how do I do that?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

And 30 seconds after posting I found the answer. There is an SQL Editor menu appeared at the top of the screen (not in the Database Navigator). Selecting SQL Editor from that brings up a query window I can type SQL into.

Comment: Do you know how to execute a multi-line sql statement without having to select the entire sql and hit ctrl + enter ? If I hit ctrl+enter after the ; it refuses to run the query preceding the ;

Comment: Sorry, can't help you on that. I pretty much stopped using DBeaver in favour of a stand alone SQL client.

Comment: to execute a query click on 'SQL Editor' menu and select 'Execute SQL Statement' (or use shortcuts for that)

Comment: @happybuddha To execute multiple sql statements from within the DBeaver editor, choose "Execute SQL Script" from the SQL Editor menu.  The shortcut is Alt+X.

Comment: Yeah, I also found this SQL Editor feature after working with DBeaver for 2 weeks. It seems that the SQL Editor is not placed in the usual place like another SQL developer UI.